# Widget initialized later will not show in MainWindow

Tags: c++, qt

I am learning `Qt` using `Qt 5.13` on `MacOS`.
First I define `MyWidget` inherited from `QWidget`. `MyWidget` has a `QPushButton`, but this button will be created in a slot function called 'fresh', not in constructor.
I add `MyWidget` in `MainWindow` (inherited from `QMainWindow`), and defined another `button_2` to emit signal to call`MyWidget`'s 'fresh' function to create button.
If I did not hide `MyWidget` in `MainWindow` first, `MyWidget`'s button will not show. If I hide `MyWidget` first, everything seems OK.
I hope to know the reason. Thanks

I tried to repaint or update `MyWidget` in 'fresh' function, but did not help.

mywidget.h

```
#ifndef MYWIDGET_H
#define MYWIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>
#include<QPushButton>

class MyWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MyWidget();

public slots:
    void fresh();

private:
    QPushButton* myButton;
};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

mywidget.cpp

```
#include "mywidget.h"

MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{

}

MyWidget::~MyWidget()
{

}


void MyWidget::fresh()
{
    myButton = new QPushButton(this);
    myButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton { background-color: green;}");
    show();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include"mywidget.h"
#include<QHBoxLayout>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

signals:

public slots:

private:
    MyWidget* myWidget;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget* qwidget = new QWidget;
    myWidget = new MyWidget(this);
    QPushButton* button = new QPushButton("Show",this);
    QHBoxLayout* mainLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
    mainLayout->addWidget(myWidget);
    mainLayout->addWidget(button);
    qwidget->setLayout(mainLayout);
    setCentralWidget(qwidget);
    //myWidget->hide();

    connect(button,&QPushButton::clicked,myWidget,&MyWidget::fresh);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mywidget.h"
#include"mainwindow.h"
#include<QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

If I add `myWidget->hide();` in mainwindow.cpp, it seems right.
If I remove it, the green button will not show, even if I repaint or update or show in fresh function.

Comment: The Button you create in `MyWidget::fresh()` never gets added to `MyWidget`s layout. `this->layout()->addWidget(myButton);`

Comment: @dave there is no layout in `MyWidget`!

Comment: @MarekR True, it will need one to display child widgets.

Comment: @dava What if I do not want a layout to manage MyWidget? And How to explain if add ```myWidget->hide()``` the green button will show even if there is no layout?

Answer (score 0):

'mywidget' is taking the whole space, if you want to know if it is taking all the space or not :

```cpp
mywidget->setStyleSheet("* {border: 4px solid orange;}")
```

Since you are using a layout, you might want to determine the minimum size of a QPushButton. the QPushButton has a default horizontal size policy : "Minimum", by default. Maybe if you set the minimum width using this function : "setMinimumWidth(int width)", might fix your problem.
Also, don't forget to call this :

```cpp
myButton->show();
```

Every object that inherits from QObject should be shown with this func ".show".
Here is all the flags for QSizePolicy will help you understand what is going on in layouts (layouts work a lot with QSizePlicy flags) : https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum .

Unless you don't want the layout, you have to specify the position and the size in this way :

```cpp
mywidget->setGeometry(QPoint(x, y), QSize(width, height));
```

and the same thing for your buttons.

Comment: Honestly, this question is a simple version of my project. I want to find a solution to let the green button initialize and show when I push the button in MainWindow using signal and slot.  Your code```mywidget->setStyleSheet("* {border: 4px solid orange;}")``` will only works on button in ```MyWidget```, I do not know your meaning that **_```mywidget``` taking the whole space_**.   But your last code ```mywidget->setGeometry(QPoint(x, y), QSize(width, height));``` is what I am using in my project code.

Comment: @huangjl . What I mean by 'taking the whole space', is it takes automatically the whole space in the layout and no space is left for button. Also, you have to call ".show" for your green button to show up.

Comment: ""setMinimumWidth(int width)", might fix your problem” - hardcoded widget sizes are a terrible idea. the default size should be just fine, add spacing to the layout if it ends up too big.